Как сделать кнопку активной после нажатия на нее
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from typing import Optional
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None,intents=disnake.Intents.all(), test_guilds=[1273029650464903350])
class Register(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value = Optional[bool]

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Дары моря", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji = "")
    async def SeaGift(self, button:disnake.ui.button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await inter.send("Выберите тип контракта", ephemeral=True, view=DropdownView())
        self.value = True
        self.stop()
    @disnake.ui.button(label="Металлург", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji = "⛏")
    async def Metal(self, button:disnake.ui.button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await inter.send("Выберите тип контракта", ephemeral=True, view=DropdownView1())
        self.value = True
        self.stop()
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def reg(ctx):
    view = Register()
    await ctx.send(f"Привет! Выбери контракт для отчета!", view=view)


bot.run("TOKEN")

После одного нажатия на любую кнопку выдает "Ошибку взаимодействия", при этом в cmd нет ошибок.
